# Create startup-script for Google GCE to create a proxy server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want a to create proxy server while creating a new instance of Google Compute Engine that will allow information to be passed from a bot that checks out automatically on shopping websites.

I know it can be done by creating a startup-script, but I don't know how can I write a startup-script to create a proxy server on Google cloud?

Help me, please!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may follow the instructions in [the GCP public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations). It shows how to configure an instance as a network proxy, and use that instance as a proxy server. The tutorial in the article is well explained.

Answer (score 0):

I have created free tool which is doing exactly this, basically will setup Google Cloud Proxy server for you.

https://createproxy.com

So you can create as many Google Cloud Proxy Servers as is your Google limit for creating instancies. If you reach this limit you can always contact Google support team to increase your instance limit, or you can create another proxy servers with different account or by different provider such as Amazon AWS, DigitalOcean, Vultr, Linode...

Also you can create/delete proxy servers by calling API https://createproxy.com/api/